# Data Harvesting Urllib2+bs4 vs Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy, screen-scraping

Data harvesting is part of my daily job and usually the way how I collect the data is using urllib2 to collect the html page and then use beautifulsoup to parse out the data I want.

I have heard of Python Scrapy package quite often. I took a look at Scrapy and what on their website is  basically talking about the importance of the general Scraping instead of 'Scrapy' itself.

I am wondering for a people who has a legit amount of knowledge of urllib2 and beautifulsoup, is Scrapy  cool or simple enough to make me abandon urllib2 and bs4 to go for?   If so, what would be the top reasons to switch?

maybe from the aspects below:

1. quickness to implement a robot
2. robustness of the robot
3. easiness to maintain your robots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my insight.

[Scrapy](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/) was designed for making web-scraping code more simple, more organized. It's also very fast (it's based on twisted).

Those spider classes, items, item pipelines really help you to organize the process of getting pages, following links, parsing responses, gathering data, storing it somewhere etc. It gives you an idea, template on how you can create your web-scraping project.

It is just much much more than `urllib2` + `bs4`, it's a framework:

> Scrapy is an application framework for crawling web sites and
>   extracting structured data which can be used for a wide range of
>   useful applications, like data mining, information processing or
>   historical archival.

There are a lot more features than I've mentioned, see this very informative [overview](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html) documentation page, especially read [What else?](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.18/intro/overview.html#what-else) section.

The choice (`urllib2` + `bs4` or `Scrapy`) really depends on the task, the complexity of web-scraping code, whether you'll need to store the crawled data somewhere or not etc.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You must always trust the answers of Alexander. He's intellectually reliable and honest :)

Comment: @Begueradj thank you for the kind words. Honestly, I'm not reliable :)

Comment: well, without your several precious convincing answers to me I would not get my diploma on this last September :) Thank you a lot generous Man.